# set type to rest url variable in php controler

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My API won't enter in the good method when I use this url: 
myserver/api/structures/close.

```
/* @Rest\Put("structures/close")
```

It enters int the method of this url:
myserver/api/structures/{id}

```
/* @Rest\Put("structures/{id}")
```

But I would like to enter in the first method. What should I do ?

I use Symfony 3, Doctrine 2

Comment: You might want to go into a bit more detail here about what you have attempted and what errors you are seeing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe you restricted {id} to be an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Put `structures/{id}` route to the end of the file, so that `structures/order` route will be matched first.
2. Restrict route's `id` parameter to be integer only (not sure if this would work)

   @Rest\Put("structures/{id}", requirements={"id": "\d+"})